# TypeScript return type of Redux action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

I have this in a codebase;

```
export const login = (user, pass) => {
  return (dispatch) =>    dispatch({ type: LOGIN });
}
```

what is the return type of `login`?

I tried this:

```
export const login = (user, pass)  : ReducerAction {
  return (dispatch) =>  dispatch({ type: LOGIN });
}
```

and that type is definitely wrong. What is the correct TS return type here? Retarded difficult to find an answer to this online.

Answer (score 1):

It will be sufficient to provide an interface for your redux action dispatch props in the following manner:

```
interface DispatchProps {
  login: () => void;
}
```

And then you can use the above interface to provided the typings for your `mapDispatchToProps`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<DispatchProps>) =>
  bindActionCreators({
    login: () => login(),
  }, dispatch);
```

If you are working with react/redux/TypeScript, I would recommend this [guide](https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide), as it has tons of resources. In addition, you might want to install [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions), which is a form of "Typesafe utilities for "action-creators" in Redux / Flux Architecture".

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that Typescript does not know the type of `dispatch`. It could be anything, as far as Typescript knows it is just some random function argument and could have `any` type. You need to declare it as the correct type and Typescript will be able to infer the rest:

```
const LOGIN = "LOGIN";

type LoginAction = {
  type: typeof LOGIN
}

const login = (user, pass) => (dispatch: React.Dispatch<LoginAction>) => dispatch({type: 'LOGIN'});
```

Note that the login action needs to have a declared type as well, because that is passed to the generic `React.Dispatch` type so that Typescript knows that kind of type it is dispatching.

You might need to install the `@types/react-redux` package to get the `React.Dispatch` type, I'm not sure where it comes from off the top of my head.